# How can we restrict a machine to access my server

Tags: api, jboss, certificate, digital

I have a JBOSS server that allows another server to make API calls.  However, I would like to limit to that particular server to access only, how can I do so using digital certificate?
please advise

Answer (score 0):

`Hello` ~ for EAP 7:

It seems you would like to restrict the connections for a specific application. 
This can be done configuring `ip-access-control` in your applications `WEB-INF/undertow-handlers.conf`:

```
ip-access-control(default-allow=false, acl={'127.0.0.1 allow', '127.0.0.2 allow'})
```

Otherwise, if you *do not want to change the app side*, you can create an expression filter directly on Undertow:

```
expression-filter name="ip-access-filter" expression="ip-access-control(default-allow=false, acl={'127.0.0.1 allow', '127.0.0.2 allow'})"/> ~~~
```

Comment: Hello thanks for your response.  However, I was restricted to use digital certificate.  Can it work?